# JavaScript: difference in efficiency of indexOf method on String and Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring, indexof

I am curious whether there exists a difference in efficiency for the `indexOf` method that is available for both `Array` and `String` in JavaScript. I thought the `indexOf` is less efficient on String than on Array, and my **new** testing results support this. For example:

```
var arr = ['abc', 'ab', 'abz', '1'];

var str = 'abcababz1';

var needle = 'abxx';

//concatenate to make them bigger
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    arr = arr.concat(arr);
    str = str.concat(str);
}
arr.push(needle);  //append needle last
str = str.concat(needle);
```

Then I used the start and end timestamp for

```
arr.indexOf(needle); // faster!
str.indexOf(needle);
```

I did this testing in node, the new testing results showed:

```
time used on Array is: 35
time used on String is: 57
```

So the Array is more efficient for indexOf than String. This new testing basically creates the worst case scenario -- needle at the very end of String or Array.

**Edit:**

If the `indexOf` is more efficient on Array, I was wondering if we should first split a String (delimited by comma, for example) to an array before using the `indexOf` method to search for a sub string.

For this string:

```
var str2 = "hello,world,country,continent,ocean"
```

If you search for `ocean`, would you first split the string `str2` to an array then use `indexOf` to find `ocean`?

```
var arr2 = str2.split(",");
arr2.indexOf('ocean');
```

Comment: I don't know what your hypothesis is or why. For that matter, I don't really even know what you're asking.

Comment: I'm with squint on this one. Those operations do two different things. It's like asking whether it's more efficient to use a Phillips head screwdriver to loosen a screw or use a nightcrawler to catch walleye. What's the end goal or scenario in which the difference matters?

Comment: One benefit that the Array has is that it can avoid the actual character by character comparison by first comparing string lengths. It only does character comparison if the lengths match. Now you seem to be wondering if you should split first, but that also would create quite a lot of overhead. As is with so many questions about performance, it all depends on the exact situation.

Comment: Yes, those two methods have the **same** name, then what? Array and string are totally different data structures, so does their `indexOf` methods' algorithms and implementations. It's not one single function applied to two data structures, they are two very different functions. So, what's the point of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing based on your edit that you want to use indexOf to check if a given element exists in your list that starts as a string.

The two options then are using indexOf on the string itself or parsing it to an array first and seeing if the element exists there, since you know the format is "item1,item2".

http://jsperf.com/indexof-array-vs-string-efficiency

Based on that jsperf we can see that even though indexOf is faster on the array itself, converting the string to an array has a cost to it as well and you're better off doing the indexOf on the raw string.

*Note that the String indexOf would need some additional modification to make sure indexOf("ocean") doesn't return true if you have an element like blueocean, and would probably instead want indexOf(",ocean,")

Comment: Interesting comparison! I added another testing for using regex: http://jsperf.com/indexof-array-vs-string-efficiency/2