# What is the best way to target an array or a string with user input, and log its respective index?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best way to target an array or a string, so that when a user types a letter it finds a match and logs the letter and its index in the array (or the string)?For example  (set-up):

```
GUESS THIS MOVIE: 

how to train your dragon
___ __ _____ ____ ______

Type a letter to guess, you have 10 TRIES:
User Typed: o

Result: _o_ _o _____ _o__ ____o_

HERES MY CODE: 
    var fs = require('fs');
    var inquirer = require('inquirer');
    var displayProgress = require('./checkGuess');

// var checkGuess = require('./checkGuess');


var PlayFunc = function() {
    var blanksArr = [];
    var currentWord = [];

this.getData = function() {
    var stackOv = "";
    fs.readFile("words.txt", "utf8", function(error, data){
        if (error) throw error;
        dataType = data.toLowerCase();
        //data in array
        var wordArr = dataType.split(',');
        //select random from word from data
        var compWord = wordArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArr.length)];//random
        //split chosen word
        currentWord = compWord.split('');
        console.log("========================\n\n\n");

        //Looping through the word          
        for (var i = 0; i <= currentWord.length - 1; i++) {
            // pushing blanks 
            var gArr = blanksArr.push("_"); 

            //HYPHENS, COLONS, SPACES SHOULD BE PASSED
            stackOv = currentWord.join("").replace(/[^- :'.]/g, "_");
            wordString = currentWord.join("");  
        }   
        console.log("GUESS THIS MOVIE: ");
        fs.writeFile("blanks.txt", stackOv, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(wordString);
            fs.readFile('blanks.txt', "utf8",(err, word) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                // console.log("GUESS THIS MOVIE: " + compWord);
                blanksTxt = word.split(''); //console.log(string.join('').replace(/[^-: '.]/g, "_"));

                displayProgress = new displayProgress();
                displayProgress.checkGuess(); 
            });
        });         
    });
}

}
module.exports = PlayFunc;
```

ON THE NEXT FILE CALLED checkGuess.js I Plan to do the checking (which goes back to my original question (OP).

```
    var fs = require('fs');
var inquirer = require('inquirer');
var PlayFunc = require('./PlayFunc');

var displayProgress = function (){
    // console.log("WORKING CONNECTED CHECKGUESS MODULE");
    // PlayFunc = new PlayFunc();
    // PlayFunc.getData();


    var a = blanksTxt.join(''); console.log(a); //string a
    var manipulateThisArray = blanksTxt;//reading from blanks.txt

    // console.log(manipulateThisArray);


     this.checkGuess = function(){
         inquirer.prompt([
       {
        type: "input",
        name: "letter",
        message: "Type a letter to guess, you have 10 TRIES:"
       }

     ]).then(function(userInput) {
        var correctArray = [];
        // console.log(userInput.letter);
        letterTyped = userInput.letter;
        //logic
        //test if we can parse through the array
        for (var i = 0; i <= manipulateThisArray.length - 1; i++) {
            x = manipulateThisArray[i]; console.log(x);
            // if userinput letter-value matches chosen words letter value 
            // replace this chosen worsa letter with userinput value
            // if(letterTyped == x.charAt(i)) {

                console.log("THERES A MATCH " + x.charAt(i));
            // }else {
                // console.log("NO MATCH");
            // }

        }
     });
}
}
// checkGuess();

module.exports = displayProgress;
```

Comment: we can assume that 'how to train your dragon' is a string OR an array

Comment: And where did you get stuck? Where's your own attempt? Where did it go wrong? Why don't you know in advance what input to expect?

Comment: You haven't provided what you have tried so far. You can actually search for the performance of `indexOf` method in array and string. I hope that is what you are looking for. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049813/javascript-difference-in-efficiency-of-indexof-method-on-string-and-array)

Comment: @Madhavan.V thanks for helping! I posted my code anyway just so people can see it.  Im 4 months into coding and learning.  THANKS again.

Answer (score 0):

```
//declaration of the variables we need
//the original string:
const string = "how to train your dragon";
//a string of characters we want to show
const show = "o";
//A resulting string we can work with
var result = "";
//Now we go over every character of our string and
for(const character of string){
  //check if the character is inside the characters we want to show
  if(show.includes(character)){
    //if so we show it by adding it to the result
    result += character;
  }else{
    //If not we add an _ instead
    result += "_";
  }
}
//At the end we can show the result
alert(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

For this i would use the `'foo'.replace('bar', 'bar')` and make sure that the String contains the input `'foo'.includes('input')` also you could use a RegExp.
To get the index you could do a loop through the length of the String and use the `'foo'.indexOf('input', number)` that will return -1 if no coincidence

Comment: And you would answer the question as asked, about how to "*log its respective index,*" how?

Comment: You could do a for looping throught the lenght of the String and use the `'foo'.indexOf('input', number)` and it should tell you the index even if it's repeated

Comment: I know, please [edit] your answer to explain that to others.

Comment: @JuanPizàFerrà I added my code.  Im blanking out as to how Im going to approach my original question on the file checkGuess.js (im 4 months into coding so, yeah Im learning)

Comment: Sorry for beeing so late, here's what i've done, in the for loop you should have the original String `var word = 'Hello'` and a blur one that is like `var blurWord = '_____'` and then loop into the world like:                                    
 `for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) { if (word.indexOf(userImput, i) != -1) {
        blurWord = blurWord.substr(0, word.indexOf(userImput, i)) +                         userImput + blurWord.substr(word.indexOf(userImput,  i)+1)                          
    }
}` Hope it does for you, sorry for indentation i'm new on this, on commenting.

Comment: Also you could save the `word.indexOf(userImput, i)` on a variable. Sory did this help you?